# Deciding clustered index in Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, indexing

We are creating this “clients” table that will have around 50 million records.

I am having a hard time deciding the ‘clustered index’.

Theory says that it should be: Unique,Narrow,Static, Ever-increasing pattern… But in practice it should be the key you use to refer to your records most often.

The table has 50 columns…

Per the first approach the CI should be:

```
[Client_id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
```

But I feel tempted to use:

```
[SF_id] [varchar](18) NOT NULL,
```

or

```
[UpdateDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
```

or

```
[SystemModStamp] [datetime] NOT NULL,
```

Reality is that I do not exactly how the end users will query the table: but, I know they will use SF_id quite often and I know they will rarely use Client_id… And I also know, me myself I will use `UpdateDate` or `SystemModStamp` (not sure yet), I will use it as the key for ‘delta’ daily merges that I will set up in a Job/SP.

Comment: you can create a clustered index on the ID column and Create non-clustered index on the most selectable columns

Comment: I would shy away from using the datetime fields. My first instinct is to use Client_id however if you can garuntee that SF_id is indeed unique for each row then you could use SF_id .

Comment: @KamranFarzami thanks! and what is the problem choosing a non-unique Clustered Index? I am pretty sure SF_id is unique, but...

Comment: if you are not sure just make [Client_id] as clustered and create a non clustered on the other three.

Comment: There isn't a problem using a non-unique column as a non clustered index. I would leave the Unique Clustered index on the primary key and use a non-clustered index on the most searched column that is not Date or Datetime

Comment: Take a look at this post: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7741/when-should-a-primary-key-be-declared-non-clustered